# AS3 pinch-zoom, and single finger drag detection

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming, drag, multi-touch

I hope someone can help with this, I have hunted high and low for the answer.

I have a custom map-app.
I have a drag class that works fine to drag the map around.
And also a pinch-zoom class that zooms the map perfectly.
But together, they get confused!

Basically, I need to decide if just one finger is down, or 2.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? Usually, touch events have an array of recognized touches. Is this how you're implementing pinch?

Comment: No, the pinch is used from the GESTURE - 
   _mapMC.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoomStart);

I then utilise the e.phase - BEGIN, UPDATE, END

Comment: Can you register both `GESTURE` and `TOUCH_POINT` events simultaneously? If so, you could use this to manually track the number of touches (as I see no way to get that data from gesture events).

Comment: What OS are you running your app on? Windows 7? Android?

Comment: For the map dragging, are you using the `TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN` etc., or are you using `TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN`? A wild guess is that multiple TransformGestureEvents will work better together than combining TouchEvent and TransformGestureEvent...

Answer (score 0):

You must add listener to TouchGestures and MouseEvents.

like this.

```
addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM , zoom);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, move);
```

and make something like

```
    private var oldx:Number = 0;
    private var oldy:Number = 0;
    //This will make the Drag
    private function move(e:MouseEvent):void{

        if(e.buttonDown){
            image.x+=e.localX-oldx;             
            image.y+=e.localY-oldy;
        }

        oldx = e.localX;
        oldy = e.localY;
    }   
    //This will deal with the zoom.
    private function zoom(e):void{
        image.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
        image.scaleY *= e.scaleY;
        //The pivot is not implemented. it must be implemented here
    }
```